# How to create Functional tests for IntegrationFlows

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I have a `StandardIntegrationFlow` which runs each day and deletes files that are older than 10 days.

```
@Bean
  public StandardIntegrationFlow oldReceiptsCleaner(
      @Qualifier("receiptSftpRemoteFileTemplate")
          RecursiveSftpRemoteFileTemplate receiptSftpRemoteFileTemplate,
      RemoteSftpFileRemover remoteSftpFileRemover) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(receiptSftpRemoteFileTemplate)
                .remoteDirectory(properties.getSftpPath()),
            e ->
                e.poller(
                    Pollers.cron(properties.getCronExpression())
                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)).id("oldReceiptsCleanerPoller"))
        .handle(remoteSftpFileRemover::removeFile)
        .get();
  }
```

I want to create a functional test to verify that it works. I have tested the code manually, by setting the cron expression to run each 2 minutes and remove files that are older than 5 mins and  but of course I need some automated tests.

I have thought to create 2 files, one which is older than 10 days and one that is not. Fetch those 2 files and verify that they exist. Then manually trigger the `StandardIntegrationFlow` using an object of `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` and calling the `.start()` function, and then try to fetch them again and verify that the one is deleted.

The first question will be if that is a proper way to test an IntegrationFlow. Also, I can't find a simple way to create the files inside the test, and change their modifiedTime.

I am using spring-integration 5.5.15 and Spock framework for testing. Also using Minio Containers to store files on server for the functional tests

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `PollerSpec` as a bean and reference it from your `oldReceiptsCleaner` flow definition. Then you override this bean in your test configuration. Then you have your `LastModifiedFileListFilter` which can be based on some property for `age` and specify desired in the test.

I'm not familiar with Minio, but probably there is API how to create files with required `lastModified`.

Then yes. You can use `@SpringIntegrationTest` with `noAutoStartup` for a bean name of your `Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter`. After you have created files, you can start that `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` manually in the test method.